# Confused to what the role of "threading.BoundedSemaphore" is in this specific script

Tags: python, python-3.x, semaphore

I'm having a really hard time understanding what "Bounded.Semaphore" is doing in this specific code. I've looked for examples and videos on YT, nothing helped. 
Here is the full code: https://github.com/tatmush/violentPython3/blob/master/Chapter-2/3-sshBrute.py

```
maxConnections = 5

connectionLock = BoundedSemaphore(value=maxConnections)
try:
    s=pxssh.pxssh()
    s.login(host, user, password)
    print('[+]Password Found: ' + password)
    found=True
    print('Found in CONNECT: {}'.format(found))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    if 'read_nonblocking' in str(e):
        logging.debug('Now in if statement')
        fails+=1
        time.sleep(5)
        connect(host, user, password, False)

    elif 'synchronize with original prompt' in str(e):
        logging.debug('Now in elif')
        time.sleep(1)
        connect(host, user, password, False)
finally:
    if release: connectionLock.release()
```

Comment: semaphores are used by threads to block access to resources or code. This semaphore probably blocks access to connection so only 5 threads can use connection at the same time.

Comment: @furas Can you please tell me why you'd use only one thread on only one function? Like, isn't that what the main thread does?

Comment: if you flage thread as 'deamon' then system may run this thread after you exit program. You get code running in background. But you can do the same with any program using `&` - ie. `python script.py &` - at least it woks on Linux. I don't know why you asked this - code in your link uses `for`-loop so it runs many threads.